# Upload a picture and create a link

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to create a php page that allows you to upload a picture to the database then immediately create a link (mywebsite.com/image/random-numbers-and-letters/) from there it would redirect to the page and so on. I am fairly new to php and could not find anything very helpful on this subject. The picture would be the only thing uploaded, no passwords, descriptions, or anything really.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a question so much as a project description. And therefore too broad to answer. Break this down into actual steps, break those down into technical problems and ask a question about one of those if you can't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

[The PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) explains how to write the HTML form for uploading, and how to move the uploaded file to the directory and filename of your choice. So just move the file to a directory in the www directory, and make the link using the filename that you choose when you moved the file.

Be sure to check for and properly handle duplicate filenames.

Comment: And a check that the file is not php or an image with php embedded or executable for that matter ;p

Comment: Right, Lawrence, definitely valid all user input. Thanks.